# ValueGeneratedOnAdd has no effect

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

For example, I have the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PK,
    firstName nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    lastName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    birtdate datetimeoffset(7) NOT NULL,
    age int,
    height int,
)
```

There is a part of entity mapping:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Person> builder)
{
    ...
    builder.HasKey(k => k.Id);

    builder.Property(k => k.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .IsRequired();
    ...
}
```

I have the MS SQL server with that table on the client side and the same table on the server side. My program retrieves data from the table on the client and sends it to server where data is added to database.
There are no problems during retrieving data but when I try to insert data I get the error:

```
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Person' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

despite of `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`

When I retrieve data I get entities with filled Id properties (1, 2, 3 etc) but I think It doesn't matter.

Comment: Are you using EF or EF Core?

Comment: @ManuelFabbri EF Core

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> When I retrieve data I get entities with filled Id properties (1, 2, 3 etc) but I think It doesn't matter.

Actually it *does* matter and is the cause of the problem. `ValueGenerated` has no effect for properties which have set value to the non default value for the type (`null` for nullable types, `0` for numeric types etc.).

The behavior is explained in the [Generated Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties) section of the EF Core documentation:

> If you add an entity to the context that has a value assigned to the property, then EF will attempt to insert that value rather than generating a new one. A property is considered to have a value assigned if it is not assigned the CLR default value (`null` for `string`, `0` for `int`, `Guid.Empty` for `Guid`, etc.). For more information, see [Explicit values for generated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties).

This is basically to allow the so called "identity inserts" scenarios when you upload data. For more info, see [Explicit values into SQL Server IDENTITY columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties).

With that being said, if you don't want that behavior, make sure all your entity `Id` (PK) properties are set to `0` before calling adding the entity to the db context/set.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But how can I set "0" value fo Id column during select and ignore values from db?

Comment: I think you should do that server side before adding, because it's specific behavior for your operation - you know you want to add new items rather than updating existing, which is the normal assumption when working with disconnected entities having the Id being set. What about doing a select, there is no easy way if you don't use explicit projection query and just return entities retrieved from the database - you have to iterate the materialized list (or whatever collection is used) and set the property to `0`.

Answer (score 6):

I solved adding `UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()` in the configuration of the Id property:

```
builder.Property(k => k.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()
    ...
```

Note that it's part of `SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions` inside *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* package.

Note, `.UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()` has been deprecated and changed to `.UseIdentityColumn()`
for "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" versions 3.x and (3.0 and 3.1 at the time of writing this)

Comment: I've literally spent hours searching for this solution. Thank you.

Comment: Identity value generation can only be used with signed integer properties. It's not going to work if Id is of Guid type.

Comment: Sure. But what would be the need of letting the database generates a Guid?

Comment: While int/bigint perform better as PrimaryKey, using GUID (uniqueidentifiers) allows one to build a complete object model and do set-based inserts.  If the client generates the guid(s), its ~easier but at the expense of bad pk fragmentation.  if the db generates guids (newsequentialids), it performs better (less pk fragmentation), but its harder to pull.    #justSayin.    Regardless, thanks for this answer!

Comment: I updated the answer for a 2.x vs 3.x tweak.  Again, thank you, this is one of those (hashtag)whereIstheExtensionMethodThisTime game winners!